# Azure Table Storage - Generic download for any type extending ITableEntity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have four custom data types, each of which extends `ITableEntity`, which is part of the `WindowsAzure.Storage` package.

Right now, I have four different methods for downloading data from the Azure Table storage. Each follows this format:

```
public List<MyCustomEntity> DownloadMyCustomEntities(string tableId)
{
    // Reference the CloudTable object
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableId);

    TableQuery<MyCustomEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyCustomEntity>();
    return new List<MyCustomEntity>(table.ExecuteQuery(query));
}
```

Instead of having one of these methods for each of my custom entity types, I am trying to create one shared function. I'm hoping this is possible, as all of my custom types inherit from `ITableEntity`.

Here is what I tried:

```
public List<TableEntity> DownloadAnyEntity(string tableId)
{
    // Reference the CloudTable object
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableId);

    TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>();
    return new List<TableEntity>(table.ExecuteQuery(query));
}
```

I've tried this with `TableEntity` and `ITableEntity`, but I keep getting errors. For `TableEntity`, my error is that no cast exists to the type I actually need (when I call the `DownloadAnyEntity` method), whereas I feel it should be implicit since it is an extension of `ITableEntity`.

For `ITableEntity`, I get an error that `ExecuteQuery` input must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor. All of my four custom types have public parameterless constructors.

I feel like the issue I'm seeing is more to do with not fully understanding inheritance, more so that it being Azure Table Storage specific. Any pointers much appreciated.

I've largely been following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet), but there is no example for a non type-specific entity download method.

Comment: Instead of `TableEntity`, can you try using `DynamicTableEntity` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dynamictableentity?view=azure-dotnet)?

Comment: Thanks - when I try this I get an issue that I can't cast from the DynamicTableEntity type to any of my custom types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the DownloadAnyEntity method generic with constraints on type parameter

```
public List<T> DownloadAnyEntity<T>(string tableId) where T: ITableEntity, new()
{
    // Reference the CloudTable object
    var tableRef = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableId);

    var query = new TableQuery<T>();
    return tableRef.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
}
```

This method can then be called for any type that inherits from the ITableEntity and has an public emtpy constructor (*The  ExecuteQuery method demands an empty construtor in order to create the entities*)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I try this, the `tableRef.ExecuteQuery` piece gives me an error that: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TElement' in the generic type or method 'CloudTable.ExecuteQuery<TElement>(TableQuery<TElement>, TableRequestOptions, OperationContect)'

Comment: @Azarantara added an update. The classes that consumes this methods need to have an empty public constuctor, else the ExecuteQuery method can't create the instances

Comment: I tried your update, it works nicely. Thanks for the quick help!